# Laravel displays field as 0 although theres a value returned

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

So the dd of a query is shown below
[image]

Whenever I try to get the value of totalsales, I get 0. My query:

```
$this->query = Sales::with(['item', 'branch'])->isSales()->groupBy('item_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, SUM(costs) as costs,SUM(profit) as profits, SUM(selling_price) as totalsales,item_id'))->orderBy('total','DESC');
    $this->query = $this->query->whereBetween('date',[$this->start_date,$this->end_date]);
    $qq = $this->query;
    $sales = $this->query->paginate($this->perPage);
```

and I output the value in a table cell in blade as follows:

```
<td>
    {{ number_format($sale->totalsales, 3) }}
 </td>
```

Note: all other attributes are displaying correctly

Thank you

Comment: try `number_format(floatval($sale->totalsales), 3)` because you seem to have a string instead of a number in that column. Though it's probably better to update your database tables if that is possible

Comment: does not work. Thanks

Comment: number_format((float) $sales->totalsales, 3)  might solve your problem.

Comment: even when I display it without any formatting, i get a 0, just FYI and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Lol... Then just add the costs with  profits and bother nomore.